# Spark Driver is not releasing memory

Tags: apache-spark, memory, memory-management, spark-streaming

In our spark streaming job, the driver memory is always accumulated and is never released. We have put in G1 garbage collection to have effective garbage collection but still it is not effective. The memory is always increasing the container failing on OOM issue at some point. What are the options to release driver memory ? Please see the trend of the memory usage of the spark driver in grafana.

Any help is appreciated.

```
"header_cols": "xxx1,xxx2,xxx3,xxx4",
"line_cols": "yyyy1,yyyy2,yyyy3,yyyy4,yyyy4,yyyy5,yyyy6",
"key" : "transaction_id"


   /* header, line and transaction_id columns are part of the same record. The application generates a nested json grouped by transaction_id, header_cols and array of transaction_id and line cols as shown below.

   |-transaction_id
   |-header_cols
            |- record 1 - line columns 
            |- record 2 - line columns
            |- record 3 - line columns 

*/
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you describe the app in more details? What does the app do? When / how is the driver used for data processing?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Thank you for your response. the application basically processes  a small pipe delimited file (< 1 MB)  and generates a nested json by grouping few columns of the record and having a line column nested array. The output of the application is a json file which is also a small file. I have update the original post with pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is highly dependant on the RAM, instead of storing data on HDD like hadoop, Spark stores data on RAM.

Usually best way to go is to .cache() for the RDD/Dataframe that you will use for multiple times. In this way you can reduce the unnecessary ram usage and speed up the data access time.

As you asked, you can free/release the RDD/Dataframe on the RAM that you won't use. You can simply use 'unpersist()' as show here.

> `rdd.unpersist()`

this code will remove the RDD/Dataframe from the RAM. Be aware if your data is important or processed, you might want to store the final version in your HDD/SDD using

> df.coalcase(1).write.format("CSV/JSON/etc").option("header", "true").save("path")